# Page permalink redirects to home page

Tags: permalinks, htaccess, linux

I've recently switched to Linux Fedora, and I moved all my xampp files to my new installation, as well as importing the databases.

Now I'm facing an odd problem, a couple of weeks ago I've created a new page on Windows and called it Resources, and created the `page-resources.php` file for it, it was working well.

I'm trying to access the url `localhost/site/resources` which was the permalink for the page I created, however, it's redirecting me to `localhost/site/` which is the home page, I tried changing the permalink settings, turning off all plugins, resetting my `.htaccess` file, even changing my site url, but no chance, and I don't know what to do.

Note: if I change the page permalink and the page slug from files, it actually works !, like if I added a letter to the name to be `localhost/site/resourcess` as well as changing the php page slug file, it's loading the page.

**UPDATE: Fixed by clearing browser's cache data and cookies :3 :D**

Comment: Thanks for the update, Mohammed. Can you please post your solution as an answer, then stop by in a couple of days and accept it? This will clear your question out of the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**: I fixed it by clearing my browser's cache, it was caching files so it used the old copy.

**BONUS**: You can load a web page without loading your caches by using `Ctrl + F5`

Answer (score 0):

Change your permalinks settings to something different, and save it. Then go back to the original settings, and save it. That should clean up your htaccess file.